# Shadow displaying when dragging image

Tags: shadow

When user upload image and when he try to drag the image , the image will display **shadow**  along with dragging, but i don't want to display the shadow....

[image]

codepen : https://codepen.io/kidsdial/pen/xMNbVz

```js
 $(document).ready(function () {
                // dont have a webserver so im using base64string instead
var maskedImageUrlb ="data:image/png;base64,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";


               
                // maskedImage two
                var mask2 = $(".container").mask({
                    maskImageUrl: maskedImageUrlb,
                    onMaskImageCreate: function (img) {
                        // add your style to the img example below
                  img.css({ "position" : "fixed" ,  "left": 173, "top": 1 })
     
      
                    }
                });
    
    

                

                fileupa2.onchange = function () {
                    mask2.loadImage(URL.createObjectURL(fileupa2.files[0]));
                };
    
    
            }); // end of document ready

// jq plugin for mask
(function ($) {
    var JQmasks = [];
    $.fn.mask = function (options) {
        // This is the easiest way to have default options.
        var settings = $.extend({
            // These are the defaults.
            maskImageUrl: undefined,
            imageUrl: undefined,
            scale: 1,
            id: new Date().getUTCMilliseconds().toString(),
            x: 0, // image start position
            y: 0, // image start position
            onMaskImageCreate: function (div) { },
        }, options);

      
        var container = $(this);
        
        let prevX = 0,
            prevY = 0,
            draggable = false,
            img,
            canvas,
            context,
            image,
            timeout,
            initImage = false,
            startX = settings.x,
            startY = settings.y,
            div;

         container.mousePosition = function(event){
           return { x: event.pageX || event.offsetX, y: event.pageY || event.offsetY };
         }
      
        container.selected = function (ev) {
             var pos = container.mousePosition(ev);
              var item =$(".masked-img canvas").filter(function(){
               var offset = $(this).offset()
                var x = pos.x - offset.left;
                var y = pos.y - offset.top;
                 var d = this.getContext('2d').getImageData(x, y, 1, 1).data;
               return d[0] >0
            });
          
            JQmasks.forEach(function(el){
               var id = item.length> 0 ? $(item).attr("id") : "";
               if (el.id ==id )
                 el.item.enable();
                else el.item.disable();
            });
        };
      
        container.enable = function(){
          draggable = true;
          $(canvas).attr("active", "true");
          div.css({ "z-index": 2 });
        }
                          
        container.disable = function(){
             draggable = false;
             $(canvas).attr("active", "false");
             div.css({ "z-index": 1 });
          }

        container.onDragStart = function (evt) {
            container.selected(evt);
            prevX = evt.clientX;
            prevY = evt.clientY;
        };

        container.getImagePosition = function () {
            return { x: settings.x, y: settings.y, scale: settings.scale };
        };

        container.onDragOver = function (evt) {
            if (draggable && $(canvas).attr("active") === "true") {
              var x = settings.x + evt.clientX - prevX;
              var y =  settings.y + evt.clientY - prevY;
                 if (x == settings.x && y == settings.y)
                   return; // position has not changed
                settings.x += evt.clientX - prevX;
                settings.y += evt.clientY - prevY;
                prevX = evt.clientX;
                prevY = evt.clientY;
                container.updateStyle();
            }
        };

        container.updateStyle = function () {
            clearTimeout(timeout);
            timeout = setTimeout(function () {
                context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
                context.beginPath();
                context.globalCompositeOperation = "source-over";
                image = new Image();
                image.setAttribute('crossOrigin', 'anonymous');
                image.src = settings.maskImageUrl;
                image.onload = function () {
                    canvas.width = image.width;
                    canvas.height = image.height;
                    context.drawImage(image, 0, 0, image.width, image.height);
                    div.css({ "width": image.width, "height": image.height });
                };

                img = new Image();
                img.src = settings.imageUrl;
                img.setAttribute('crossOrigin', 'anonymous');
                img.onload = function () {
                    settings.x =settings.x == 0 && initImage ? (canvas.width - (img.width * settings.scale )) / 2 : settings.x;
                    settings.y =settings.y == 0 && initImage ? (canvas.height - (img.height * settings.scale )) / 2 : settings.y;
                    context.globalCompositeOperation = 'source-atop';
                    context.drawImage(img, settings.x, settings.y, img.width * settings.scale, img.height * settings.scale);
                    initImage = false;
                };
            }, 0);
        };

        // change the draggable image
        container.loadImage = function (imageUrl) {
            if (img)
                img.remove();
            // reset the code.
            settings.y = startY;
            settings.x = startX;
            prevX = prevY = 0;
            settings.imageUrl = imageUrl;
            initImage = true;
            container.updateStyle();
        };

        // change the masked Image
        container.loadMaskImage = function (imageUrl, from) {
            if (div)
                div.remove();
            canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
            context = canvas.getContext('2d');
            canvas.setAttribute("draggable", "true");
            canvas.setAttribute("id", settings.id);
            settings.maskImageUrl = imageUrl;
            div = $("<div/>", {
                "class": "masked-img"
            }).append(canvas);

            div.find("canvas").on('touchstart mousedown', function (event) {
                if (event.handled === false) return;
                event.handled = true;
                container.onDragStart(event);
            });

            div.find("canvas").on('touchend mouseup', function (event) {
                if (event.handled === false) return;
                event.handled = true;
                container.selected(event);
            });

            div.find("canvas").bind("dragover", container.onDragOver);
            container.append(div);
            if (settings.onMaskImageCreate)
                settings.onMaskImageCreate(div);
            container.loadImage(settings.imageUrl);
        };
        container.loadMaskImage(settings.maskImageUrl);
        JQmasks.push({item: container , id: settings.id})
        return container;
    };
}(jQuery));
```

```css
.container {
    border: 1px solid #DDDDDD;
    display: flex;
    background: red;
 width:612px;
 height:612px;
}

.container canvas {
    display: block;
}

.masked-img {
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-top: 50px;
    position: relative;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js">
</script>



image 2 
<input id="fileupa2"  type="file" >



<div class="container">

</div>
```

I don't want to display shadow when dragging....

Please let me know if you have any doubts on this....

Thanks in Advance....

Comment: that picture tho

Comment: @Neoares i just uploaded some random image, you can choose any other image, can you please help me for this ?

Comment: What do you mean by shadow? while dragging the image is appearing above the heart pattern did you mean that?

Comment: thats right...... @FirozTennali , means original image is still inside , but one more [shadow image ] will display outside the `heart` , i dont want that.....

Comment: Instead of draggable canvas use the jquery ui dragging and upload image inside the container, it gives smooth dragging I you will not feel the flutter or any flashing. or try with the increasing z-index of container

Comment: @FirozTennali before i was doing the same, but i faced problems in dragging if two images overlapp as in [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54767885/dragging-only-in-some-part-of-image) , [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54759848/dragging-multiple-images-inside-another-image) , so only i used those code....

Comment: What is the problem here: https://codepen.io/kidsdial/pen/JxxQRv, On dragg active change the z-index of the image.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188803/discussion-between-vickey-colors-and-firoz-tennali).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Listen for the `dragStart` event :

```
div.find("canvas").on('dragstart', function (event) {
```

so you can use [DataTransfer.setDragImage()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DataTransfer/setDragImage) :

> When a drag occurs, a translucent image is generated from the drag target (the element the dragstart event is fired at), and follows the mouse pointer during the drag. This image is created automatically, so you do not need to create it yourself. However, if a custom image is desired, the **DataTransfer.setDragImage()** method can be used to set the custom image to be used. The image will typically be an  element but it can also be a  or any other image element.

And update the `container.onDragStart` function to :

```
container.onDragStart = function (evt) {
  container.selected(evt);
  prevX = evt.clientX;
  prevY = evt.clientY;
  evt.originalEvent.dataTransfer.setDragImage(null, 0, 0); // add this line
};
```

Here's an example with a custom " shadow" iamge :

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  // dont have a webserver so im using base64string instead
  var maskedImageUrlb = "data:image/png;base64,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";



  // maskedImage two
  var mask2 = $(".container").mask({
    maskImageUrl: maskedImageUrlb,
    onMaskImageCreate: function(img) {
      // add your style to the img example below
      img.css({
        "position": "fixed",
        "left": 173,
        "top": 1
      })


    }
  });


  fileupa2.onchange = function() {
    mask2.loadImage(URL.createObjectURL(fileupa2.files[0]));
  };


}); // end of document ready

// jq plugin for mask
(function($) {
  var JQmasks = [];
  $.fn.mask = function(options) {
    // This is the easiest way to have default options.
    var settings = $.extend({
      // These are the defaults.
      maskImageUrl: undefined,
      imageUrl: undefined,
      scale: 1,
      id: new Date().getUTCMilliseconds().toString(),
      x: 0, // image start position
      y: 0, // image start position
      onMaskImageCreate: function(div) {},
    }, options);


    var container = $(this);

    let prevX = 0,
      prevY = 0,
      draggable = false,
      img,
      canvas,
      context,
      image,
      timeout,
      initImage = false,
      startX = settings.x,
      startY = settings.y,
      div;

    container.mousePosition = function(event) {
      return {
        x: event.pageX || event.offsetX,
        y: event.pageY || event.offsetY
      };
    }

    container.selected = function(ev) {
      var pos = container.mousePosition(ev);
      var item = $(".masked-img canvas").filter(function() {
        var offset = $(this).offset()
        var x = pos.x - offset.left;
        var y = pos.y - offset.top;
        var d = this.getContext('2d').getImageData(x, y, 1, 1).data;
        return d[0] > 0
      });

      JQmasks.forEach(function(el) {
        var id = item.length > 0 ? $(item).attr("id") : "";
        if (el.id == id)
          el.item.enable();
        else el.item.disable();
      });
    };

    container.enable = function() {
      draggable = true;
      $(canvas).attr("active", "true");
      div.css({
        "z-index": 2
      });
    }

    container.disable = function() {
      draggable = false;
      $(canvas).attr("active", "false");
      div.css({
        "z-index": 1
      });
    }

    container.onDragStart = function(evt) {
      container.selected(evt);
      prevX = evt.clientX;
      prevY = evt.clientY;
      var img = new Image();
      img.src = 'https://www.what-dog.net/Images/faces2/scroll001.jpg';
      evt.originalEvent.dataTransfer.setDragImage(img, 10, 10);
    };

    container.getImagePosition = function() {
      return {
        x: settings.x,
        y: settings.y,
        scale: settings.scale
      };
    };

    container.onDragOver = function(evt) {
      if (draggable && $(canvas).attr("active") === "true") {
        var x = settings.x + evt.clientX - prevX;
        var y = settings.y + evt.clientY - prevY;
        if (x == settings.x && y == settings.y)
          return; // position has not changed
        settings.x += evt.clientX - prevX;
        settings.y += evt.clientY - prevY;
        prevX = evt.clientX;
        prevY = evt.clientY;
        container.updateStyle();
      }
    };

    container.updateStyle = function() {
      clearTimeout(timeout);
      timeout = setTimeout(function() {
        context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        context.beginPath();
        context.globalCompositeOperation = "source-over";
        image = new Image();
        image.setAttribute('crossOrigin', 'anonymous');
        image.src = settings.maskImageUrl;
        image.onload = function() {
          canvas.width = image.width;
          canvas.height = image.height;
          context.drawImage(image, 0, 0, image.width, image.height);
          div.css({
            "width": image.width,
            "height": image.height
          });
        };

        img = new Image();
        img.src = settings.imageUrl;
        img.setAttribute('crossOrigin', 'anonymous');
        img.onload = function() {
          settings.x = settings.x == 0 && initImage ? (canvas.width - (img.width * settings.scale)) / 2 : settings.x;
          settings.y = settings.y == 0 && initImage ? (canvas.height - (img.height * settings.scale)) / 2 : settings.y;
          context.globalCompositeOperation = 'source-atop';
          context.drawImage(img, settings.x, settings.y, img.width * settings.scale, img.height * settings.scale);
          initImage = false;
        };
      }, 0);
    };

    // change the draggable image
    container.loadImage = function(imageUrl) {
      if (img)
        img.remove();
      // reset the code.
      settings.y = startY;
      settings.x = startX;
      prevX = prevY = 0;
      settings.imageUrl = imageUrl;
      initImage = true;
      container.updateStyle();
    };

    // change the masked Image
    container.loadMaskImage = function(imageUrl, from) {
      if (div)
        div.remove();
      canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
      context = canvas.getContext('2d');
      canvas.setAttribute("draggable", "true");
      canvas.setAttribute("id", settings.id);
      settings.maskImageUrl = imageUrl;
      div = $("<div/>", {
        "class": "masked-img"
      }).append(canvas);

      div.find("canvas").on('dragstart', function(event) {
        if (event.handled === false) return;
        event.handled = true;
        container.onDragStart(event);
      });

      div.find("canvas").on('touchend mouseup', function(event) {
        if (event.handled === false) return;
        event.handled = true;
        container.selected(event);
      });

      div.find("canvas").bind("dragover", container.onDragOver);
      container.append(div);
      if (settings.onMaskImageCreate)
        settings.onMaskImageCreate(div);
      container.loadImage(settings.imageUrl);
    };
    container.loadMaskImage(settings.maskImageUrl);
    JQmasks.push({
      item: container,
      id: settings.id
    })
    return container;
  };
}(jQuery));
```

```css
.container {
  border: 1px solid #DDDDDD;
  display: flex;
  background: red;
  width: 612px;
  height: 612px;
}

.container canvas {
  display: block;
}

.masked-img {
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-top: 50px;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js">
</script>
image 2
<input id="fileupa2" type="file">

<div class="container">
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this worked fine , when we drag the image, its blinking everytime as in this [video](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1GkP5wxWPTPZlMKBhKWS-XDh4M31jHgpK/view) , is there any way to stop that ?

Comment: I guess the flashing is because the constant redraws in `updateStyle()`, i'll look into that,

Comment: hi, i'm still looking at it, i can't figure out hwo to fix the flashing yet,

Comment: The first argument to `setDragImage` must be an `Element` and modern browsers enforce it.


Using `null` produces  `Failed to execute 'setDragImage' on 'DataTransfer': parameter 1 is not of type 'Element'.`


You can use an empty element instead, e.g. 

    `evt.originalEvent.dataTransfer.setDragImage(document.createElement('div'), 0, 0);`

or, since you're using jQuery:

    `evt.originalEvent.dataTransfer.setDragImage($('<div>')[0], 0, 0);`