# how to hide shadow of draggable div while dragging

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, draggable

I have a draggable div. when I dragging a `div` then the shadow of `div` move with actual `div`. So I just want to hide the shadow of actual `div`.

```html
<div draggable="true" 
  (dragstart)="mousedown($event)"
  (drag)="dragging($event)" 
  (dragover)="allowDrop($event)">
  div contents
</div>
```

Please help!!

Comment: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54801303/shadow-displaying-when-dragging-image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54801303/shadow-displaying-when-dragging-image)

Comment: its not working for me. when i used this then my div is not move anymore

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could just use the event.target and position it using the window's `outerWidth` and `outerHeight`

```js
document.addEventListener("dragstart", function( event ) {
  event.dataTransfer.setDragImage(event.target, window.outerWidth, window.outerHeight);
}, false);
```